# Gradient, normal and tangent of curves / surfaces in 2 and 3 dimensions

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I have a question regarding how the gradient is related to the tangent and normal of curves / surfaces in 2 and 3 dimensions.

From what I've gathered, the gradient of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is normal to the surface at a specific point.

To illustrate, take the surface $x^2 + y^2 - z=0$. Calculating the gradient of $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2-z$ gives us $\nabla f(x, y, z) = (2x, 2y, -1)$. Evaluating the gradient at $(2, 1, 5)$ gives us a normal to the surface $f=0$ at that point: $\nabla f(2, 1, 5) = (4, 2, -1)$.

Now, for the gradient of a curve in $\mathbb R^2$ this does not seem to the case. Take the curve $f(x, y) = y - x^2$. Calculating the gradient gives us $\nabla f(x, y) = (-2x, 1)$. If we evaluate the gradient at $(1, 1)$ we get $\nabla f(1, 1) = (-2, 1)$. Converting this into a line we get $y = 2x$. This gives us a tangent to the curve $f=0$ (that is, $y = x^2$) at $(1, 1)$.

How does these two cases relate and why is the gradient to a curve in $R^2$ not the normal of the curve?

Comment: The direction of the gradient at $(1,1)$ should be normal to the curve $(1,1)$.  Is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is when you "convert into a line". I don't know exactly what you did. However, if you just focus on the vector $(-2,1)$ on the $xy$ plane (draw it!), then this vector is clearly normal to the parabola in the point $x=1$. The line having direction $(-2,1)$ and passing by the point $(1,1)$ is $ y=3/2-x/2$, not $y=2x$. This line is not even passing by $(1,1)$!

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to guestDiego, for people who are still thinking about where the OP went wrong (like me!)-

OP took the derivative of the function $ \frac{dy}{dx} = 2x$. Since this is the slope of the line, he wrote the equation of the tangent, forgetting to add the constant term (-1).

A small graph, if it helps 
[image: 2D graph of y=x^2]

Clearly, the tangent is not normal to the curve. We just found the tangent slope using the derivative of the function. Numerous sources state that the derivative points in the normal direction to the curve. So, what magic took place here? This is what is answered above.

I've two takeaways here-

1. Write in functional form like OP has and the derivative gives the direction vector of the normal to the function (curve).
2. What we do in lower level (2D) math where y=f(x) is not a good way to talk about functions. It indicates an inherent tendency to plot in a higher dimension which creates issues. Instead, look at a function as a family of curves. Then the idea that moving normal to the curve changes function value makes a lot more sense.